# Redirect based on set cookie

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cookies, redirect

I have a bilingual website. 
The user should be automatically redirected to the appropriate subdirectory `/en/` and `/de/` based on his browser language. I achieve that via .htaccess.

On the website is a language switcher if the user nevertheless wants to switch the language. When the language is switched, there’s a  cookie set which contains either the value `en` or `de`.

Now I’d like my htaccess to check if there’s a cookie set and if yes: Check the value and redirect to the appropriate folder. If not: Check the browser language and redirect to the appropriate folder.

This is what I have so far but it gives me an error: Too many redirects …

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} Test=en; [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/en [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} Test=de; [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/de [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^de [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/de [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/en [L,R=301]
```

This is the code that generates the cookie:

```
if (session_id() == '') {
  session_start();
}

$lang = basename ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );

setcookie("Test", $lang);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not restricting the redirection when the URL has already been redirected once. This is causing the infinite redirection loop.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:en|de) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} test=(en|de) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^de [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/de [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/en [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for the hint! What I now get is something like `http://example.com/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en` …

Comment: I updated my question with the code that generates the cookie. Maybe that helps.